# Why do php redis get data returns with colons

Tags: php, redis

### The problem

I wrote a multi-threaded implementation of the code and tried to use redis as a counter, this is my code. When I try to use redis as a counter, I often get ':'(colon) in the value, sometimes not, is it because I loop too fast and redis doesn't even notice?

### Output result

```bash
cclilshy@192 debug % php st.php
registerRedis success!
registerSocket success!
1
2
3
1
2
string(2) ":5"
1
2
3
string(2) ":9"
3
string(1) "9"

// the up is the output. Why?
```

### Code

```php
$func = function($handle){
    for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
        echo $handle->counter().PHP_EOL;
    }

    var_dump($handle->total());
};

//$handle->counter() :
public function counter($record = true){
        if($record = false){
            return $this->count;
        }
        $this->thread->counter();
        $this->count++;
        return $this->count;
}

//$handle->total() :
public function total(){
        return $this->thread->counter(false);
}

//$handle->thread->counter() : 
public function counter($record = true){
        if($record === false){
            return $this->redis->get('thread.' . $this->pids[0] . '.count');
        }
        return $this->redis->incr('thread.' . $this->pids[0] . '.count');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using a separate redis connection for each process

Answer (score 0):

Redis is single-threaded by design, so it's anyway serves your threads in sync way.

Response looks like this because [RESP](https://redis.io/docs/reference/protocol-spec/) protocol are not parsed and it returns you raw representation for integer.

Yeah, one of the reason could be that parser process is still blocked at the time you're already returns next value